# Image textures are only displayed in edit mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I created, unwrapped, and textured an object in **edit mode**.
However, when I switch to **object mode** (or try to render the object) the image textures included in the material I created disappear from the surface of the object.  In both cases, Viewport Shading is set to Material.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit mode:
[image: The textures, displays in edit mode]

Object mode:
[image: The same object, but the texture disappeared]

Material node setup:
[image: The nodes used for my robot material]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm. Got any modifiers?

Comment: I am using a bevel and a remesh modifier on the object.

Comment: I just deactivated the remesh, now the texture appears with the material.  Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was being caused by a Remesh modifier. Deactivating the modifier fixed the issue.